# Using complex property with custom component?

Tags: angular, angular2-custom-component

If i pass complex inputs (prop.childprop) as string getting error **"Cannot read property 'property' of undefined"**

```
export function NewComponent(name:string, componentArgs: {
selector: string,
inputs: Array<string> 
}): Type<any> {
var comp = Component(componentArgs);
return comp.Class({        
})
}
```

When creating component as follow getting error **"Cannot read property 'property' of undefined"**

```
 NewComponent(selector:'mycom',inputs:["prop","prop.childprop"])
```

Using **Component()** to create component

Comment: Cay you please add/update your code in typescipt

Comment: @sudheerKB Posted code only my typescript code

Comment: please let us know what you are going to do and why you wrote NewComponent function

Comment: please add plunkr link